# Google Calendar breaking when calling "listEvents($calendarId)" in PHP

Tags: php, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API and created a working list view of several calendars on my website. However, overnight, the calendar stopped working (without any changes to the website as far as I know) and it breaks as soon as the function "$cal->events->listEvents($calendarId)" is called where $cal is "new Google_Service_Calendar($client)"

My PHP code

```
require_once('api/googleoauth/autoload.php'); 

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My APP"); 
$client->setDeveloperKey('my-developer-key'); 


$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarId = 'mycalendar@gmail.com';    

$calendar = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId);//<--breaks here
$events = $calendar->getItems();
```

I haven't changed the code that was working yesterday so that should narrow the problem down to either my server, or settings in Google Developers.

My question is, since the page simply breaks without showing any error (similar to die();) How do I check where the problem lies? Did Google make changes to their API? Am I over some quota in query calls?

-I have Google calendar API enabled on google.developers,

-My server seems to be running PHP and including files just fine.

-I can print_r($cal) and print_r($cal->events) but not $cal->events->listEvents()

Comment: I don't think its problem from Google side. When I tried to list the events(using events.list) in my calendar, it displayed all the events. you can try example request here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list. It could be problem with your server.